# Aligning page elements with window size

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery

The following is a series of functions to ensure that various elements on a page line up no matter what window size or when the window is resized. However I'm not sure my code is very concise as I am using the same function on three different event handlers. I read that function expressions aren't "hoisted" so I can't get the proper values on `$(document).ready` but I'm not sure how I could declare them with out making the code really messy and repetitive.

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sbt75/342/) with the complete HTML and CSS.

```
 function captHeight(){
    var figCaption = $('.cap-bot').find($('figcaption'));
    var captionHeight = Math.max.apply(null, $('figcaption').map(function ()
      {
          return $(this).height();
    }).get());

    $('.cap-bot').css({
      'overflow': 'visible'
      });
      figCaption.css({
      'position': 'relative',
      'opacity': '1',
      'bottom': '0', 
      'min-height': captionHeight+ 20 + "px" //to account for padding
      });
}

function sameHeight(){
if($('.find-height').length > 0){
    var foundHeight= $('.find-height').height();
    var gaveHeight= $('.give-height').height();


    if (gaveHeight > foundHeight){
      captHeight();     
    }

    $('.give-height').css({
      'min-height': foundHeight
    });
  }
} 

$(document).ready(function(){
  sameHeight();
});

$(window).on('resize', function(){
  sameHeight();
});

$(window).on('scroll', function(){
  sameHeight();
});
```

Comment: Hoisting doesn't matter here. You should be able to just do `$(sameHeight); $(window).on("resize scroll", sameHeight);` and done

Comment: I thought hoisting might be why it doesn't seem to work on `document.ready` only when it scrolls as it is getting the height before the `captHeight()` is applied. Otherwise cheers for the tidier function calls. I didn't know you could use them together like that. If you want to submit it as an answer it seems good to me.

Comment: Your jsfiddle seems to work fine on document.ready with either your code or the one I suggested. In any case, hoisting is only relevant within the execution of the script itself (i.e. in what order are things written), but has nothing to do with _timing_ of said execution, which is what could be problematic (e.g. trying to manipulate elements before they've been loaded or laid out)

Comment: If you take out the `on.('scroll')` it doesn't work on `document.ready` that said it is almost impossible for it not to work as one would have to scroll to see that part but I can't work out why it wouldn't. So I'm guessing the problem is about timing as you said.

Comment: Timing isn't an issue here (it could be, if the code was different, but not the way it is). And taking out the `on('scroll')` doesn't break anything for me. The fiddle works fine with only the `ready` event (as indeed it should)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that function expressions aren't "hoisted"

Yes. See [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname).

> so I can't get the proper values on $(document).ready

Why that? Unless the assignment to `sameHeight` did happen after the `$(document).ready` call, you can easily get the function.

> but I'm not sure how I could declare them with out making the code really messy and repetitive.

You already have *declared* them, they are hoisted and everything is fine. However, even if you did use function expressions:

```
var captHeight = function() {
    …
};
var sameHeight = function() {
    …
};
$(document).ready…
```

then everything would have been fine. Notice that, as @Flambino mentioned already in the comments, you can shorten the part where you install the event listener to

```
$(document).ready(sameHeight);

$(window).on('resize', sameHeight)
         .on('scroll', sameHeight);
```